# Identify line weight in batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, postscript

Does anybody know of a way to automatically identify the thickness of lines in a postscript file, and automatically apply a .25pt stroke to any file that registers a thickness below 3pts?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to modify the stroke operator. Because PostScript is a programming language you can do this. For example:

```
/old_stroke /stroke load def
/stroke {
  currentlinewidth == flush
  old_stroke
} bind def
```

will print the current value of the line width in the graphics state,whenever a stroke is performed. However there is a complication, the line width is (like everything else) affected by the Current Transformation Matrix.

In order to get the effective width you need to take the CTM into account, bearing in mind that the transformation need not be isomorphic, ie it can be scaled differently in the x and y directions.

Comment: THat also, but it need not be isomorphic either